# How to open Activity.openOptionsMenu() from a service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-optionsmenu

I have a service (it's for communications) that needs to call openOptionsMenu() of the current running activity. I have about 3 or so activities that need to show their options menu upon this request from the service. How can I find this current running activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd suggest is that from the active Activity you call bindService() and open a connection to the service. One of the methods defined on your Service's binder connection should take a Binder as an argument. The Activity will instantiate this Binder and pass it into the Service's binder method. When the interesting event happens, the Service should invoke a method on Binder that the Activity passed it.

When one of your Activities goes into the background, it should unregister the Binder it previously passed in and unbind from the Service.

So, you've have an AIDL for the Service that looks something like

```
interface IServiceConnection {
    void registerCallback(IActivityCallback callback);
    void unregisterCallback(IActivityCallback callback);
}
```

Then you have an IActivityCallback.aidl that looks like

```
oneway interface IActivityCallback {
    void openOptionsMenu();
}
```

In your Service you have

```
private ArrayList<IActivityCallback> mCallbacks = new ArrayList<IActivityCallback>();
private IServiceConnection.Stub mBinder = new IServiceConnection.Stub() {
    public void registerCallback(IActivityCallback callback) { 
        mCallbacks.add(callback);
    }

    public void registerCallback(IActivityCallback callback) { 
        mCallbacks.remove(callback);
    }
}

private void onEvent() {
    for (int ptr = mCallbacks.size() - 1; ptr > -1; ptr--) {
        mCallbacks.get(ptr).openOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

In your Service's onBind method you return mBinder.

In your activity you have

```
private IActivityCallback.Stub mPlayerBinder = new IActivityCallback.Stub() {
    public void openOptionsMenu() {
        // call method in Activity to show options menu
    }
}
```

You bind to your Service from your Activity with a bindService call and when the ServiceConnection receives onServiceConnected you cast its stub to IServiceConnection and then invoke the registerCallback method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't advise that plan of action. Manipulating and UI features without the users permission and foreknowledge is unkind. But to do it, you will need a solid reference to your Activity maintained via a static field or a field in your Application extension (or a singleton state machine etc...).

Comment: Well the user causes the call to open the options menu in the service. I have the context of the current activity saved in a static class. So can i call like this:  SomeClass.SaticClass.getContext().openOptionsMenu();? I have noticed that eclipse wants me to typecast Activity to the getContext() method.